# Why when I remove some referenceBlock are shown javascript errors in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2

I needed to set display='false' in some referenceBlock from my Home Page:

[image]

Now when display Home Page are shown javascript errors:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thank's.